# Provide backwards compatibility layer with older versions of the ECore

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

I use EMF to store the main data of my application. However, the ECore model evolves over time. Every time a new release is done, I use a different base URI for my package. This way, it remains very clear which version a file was stored in.

I would like to add a backwards compatibility layer. This way, I can also read older versions and convert them to a new version of the model. How would I go about this? Can I just use an older version of the .Ecore to parse the file reflectively and try to create a new model automatically? How do you guys do this in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the EMF recipes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Recipes#XMI.2FXML_Serialization_Recipes)